# Windows MFC application loses focus on startup after recent windows 10 updates

Tags: windows-10, boot, c++, window-focus

We have an application built in MFC (c++), originally working on windows XP, then 7 and now windows 10.

The problem we faced was the lost of focus, which was randomly stealead by windows messages and other apps. We solved that by running the app trough a command line with the following command:

start /wait PATH

The "/wait" solved all the focus problems, but with the recent windows updates it stopped working again. Since I couldn't find any results about it, does anyone already experienced this issue or have any alternatives to the "/wait" command?

Answer (score 1):

There is utility called "Always on top" that will probably do the trick for you.

[How To Keep a Window Always On Top in Windows 10](https://www.techjunkie.com/always-on-top-windows-10/)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977322/set-the-window-position-of-an-application-via-command-line

Comment: Thanks. We actually built an workaround for this which was moving the mouse cursor to the center of the screen and generating click events every time the app detected lost of focus. I am just sad we don't have some kind of feature that deals with focus issues natively on windows

Comment: Do you have SOURCE for this app???  That would change everything! :)

Comment: Of course windows has ways to deal with this.  The biggest question is WHAT rogue sketch app is playing bad and stealing your focus.  This is not normal but also can happen in any window manager.  If you have the source, use the flag WS_EX_TOPMOST in your window creation call.  If you can't find that call, your window class has a member "m_hWnd", use this call "SetWindowPos(m_hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);"